# SpamAssassin rule for emails with multiple TO email addresses?

Tags: spamassassin

I'm getting pummelled my spammers who are sending emails that don't really score for some reason:

```
X-Spam-Score: 5
X-Spam-Bar: /
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "brian2022.newbyhost.com",
 has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
 message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
 similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
 @@CONTACT_ADDRESS@@ for details.
 
 Content preview:  ety ykjebe vehlej ety ykjebe vehlej 
 
 Content analysis details:   (0.5 points, 4.0 required)
 
  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  0.5 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at https://www.dnswl.org/,
                              no trust
                             [40.92.21.79 listed in list.dnswl.org]
```

Part of the problem I think is the content is too small:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Diso-8859-=
1">
<style type=3D"text/css" style=3D"display:none;"> P {margin-top:0;margin-bo=
ttom:0;} </style>
</head>
<body dir=3D"ltr">
<div style=3D"font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size=
: 12pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
ety ykjebe vehlej </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(it then has an attachment, which I guess would have a link to their site - but I've dared open it!)

One of things I'm hoping I can filter on, is when they are (for example) 5 or more people in the `To:` column. I've tried looking online to see if an existing rule exists for this, but have come up empty.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK so technically this doesn't answer my question, but it does work for what I need with the same end-game. I realised I could add in a rule to my **/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template** file, which would reject any emails that have too many "to" addresses:

```
  deny     message = Too many recipients
         condition = ${if >{ ${listcount:${addresses:$h_To:,$h_Cc:}} }{5} {yes}{no}}
```

This now works exactly how I want, and they bounce with:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data:
550 Too many recipients
```

Hopefully this helps someone else trying to acheive the same thing